# Appium iOS automation via Wifi

Tags: ios, appium

I'm working on an automation project for iOS, and I've been googling on if it's possible to run automation tests with appium through the Wifi on a real device without having the device plugged in into the pc. In my understanding, I think it's not possible and googling it haven't seen any one say other wise (May I'm just googling it wrong). Has anyone had to do automation on iOS device via wifi?. The AUT is a hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute test on iphone browser (webview) by using selenium's iphoneDriver not by appium, follow this:

1. Get iwebdriver code by executing this on terminal: svn checkout http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ and Install iwebdriver in iPhone using xcode and start it in device, once you start this, there will a url displayed at the bottom of app in iPhone, use it in below code at iphoneIp = http://ip;
2. initialise remote driver in your test.
   RemoteWebDriver iphoneDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(iphoneIp), cap);
3. Then write your test as usual.

Comment: Hey thanks, on the answer, does it work on a hybrid app?  I just realized I didn't make it clear.

Comment: It should work on mobile web based application, haven't tried for app.

Comment: Also iPhoneDriver wasn't depricated in favor of use of Appium or Selendriod?